# How to do reusable function in react

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, react-props

I am new in react stuff. My code structure look like this:

```
App - Calls - CallsChart - chart1
                         - chart2
                         - ...
    - Home  - HomeCharts - chart3
                         - chart4 ...
    - filter bar
    - type bar
    - navigation bar
```

So every dashboard (Calls, Home...) has bars and charts inside. But when user click on chart to generate new filter, I need this value to propagate from chart1 - CallsChart - Calls - App - filter bar. I am passing these parameters in props. For example:

```
//get filter
clickFilter(filter){
    this.props.chartFilter(filter);
}
```

But I need to define these basic function on every level of the way up (and down). How can I make these functions reusable? Define them only once and use them in every dashboard? I have found out that react doesn't have inheritance but it uses composition. I can't make this because I am just passing a parameter to parent.

Answer (score 2):

As Dupocas said, you can wrap all your components in a top level component who manages your state. But also, if that is not your preference for your application, you can use React Redux to manage the application state as a single state changed only by actions. You can learn more at [Using React Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance in react is acomplished by hierarchy, if you need to propagate state to other components a elegant solution would be to wrap your components on a stateful parent component. In this way you fetch all the data you need and then distributes to it's children via `props`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting to create one "top" component and it's children will be Calls,Home... or the charts? Can you write me an example?